# Syntax error with Verilog web examples, are there multiple variants of Verilog syntax?

Tags: syntax, module, verilog

I'm trying to compile some very basic Verilog files where the module inputs/outputs are given by an instructor and I write a single dataflow assignment, but I get syntax errors on the instructor's part.  This is a stripped down version of the source file:

```
module syntax1 (
  input A, B,
  output C
  );

  assign C = A && B; // Only line that I can modify

endmodule
```

I compile it with `verilog syntax1.v` and get this output:

```
Host command: [path removed for stackoverflow]/verilog.exe
Command arguments:
    syntax1.v

Tool:   VERILOG-XL  08.20.001-d log file created Jan  9, 2016  17:56:34
Tool:   VERILOG-XL  08.20.001-d   Jan  9, 2016  17:56:34

[license is here]

Compiling source file "syntax1.v"

Error!    syntax error                                      [Verilog]          
          "syntax1.v", 2: input<-

Error!    Input, output or inout (C) not defined in port                       
          list                                              [Verilog-INOPL]    
          "syntax1.v", 3: 

Error!    syntax error                                      [Verilog]          
          "syntax1.v", 4: )<-

Error!    Identifier (A) not declared                       [Verilog-IDSND]    
          "syntax1.v", 6: 

Error!    Identifier (B) not declared                       [Verilog-IDSND]    
          "syntax1.v", 6: 
5 errors
End of Tool:    VERILOG-XL  08.20.001-d   Jan  9, 2016  17:56:34
```

If I change the first three lines (which I would hope is not what I have to do) and recompile, it works:

```
module syntax2 (A, B, C);
  input A, B;
  output C;

  assign C = A && B;

endmodule
```

Verilog output:

```
Host command: [path removed for stackoverflow]/verilog.exe
Command arguments:
    syntax2.v

Tool:   VERILOG-XL  08.20.001-d log file created Jan  9, 2016  17:49:02
Tool:   VERILOG-XL  08.20.001-d   Jan  9, 2016  17:49:02

[license is here]

Compiling source file "syntax2.v"
Highest level modules:
syntax2

0 simulation events (use +profile or +listcounts option to count)
CPU time: 0.0 secs to compile + 0.0 secs to link + 0.0 secs in simulation
End of Tool:    VERILOG-XL  08.20.001-d   Jan  9, 2016  17:49:03
```

So either Verilog doesn't like inputs and outputs declared in the argument list, or I am doing something wrong. I see web examples that do it like it's done in `syntax1.v`, so I would think it's a configuration issue on my end. Am I potentially compiling against a different version of Verilog than I should be?

Comment: Verilog-XL is a tool that has been out of development for over 20 years. The latest version of Verilog that it supported was 1364-1995.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code you is using ANSI style header which is supported in IEEE Std 1364-2001 (aka Verilog-2001) and above. According to Wikipedia's [List of HDL sinulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HDL_simulators), Verilog-XL only supports IEEE Std 1364-1995 (aka Verilog-1995). Maybe Cadence added Verilog-2001 support and it is not documented on Wikipedia, look for or try `-2001`, `-v2k`, or similar command line options.

You masked your path, so I cannot tell if you have Verilog-XL installed as standalone or via Cadence Incisive. If if you have Incisive, try running with `ncverilog` or `irun` instead of `verilog`

You should consider changing to another simulator. Modern simulators are not limited to Verilog-1995.

If you want to continue using Verilog-XL, you will need to change the header style to Non-ANSI style; example below. Note: Verilog-1995 does not support `@*`, therefor FSM will be harder to write unless you use scripts to declare the sensitivity list for you.

```
module syntax1 ( A, B, C );
  input A;
  input B;
  output C;

  assign C = A && B; // Only line that I can modify

endmodule
```